# Wordpress Modal contact form using CF7 and Easy Fancybox not working?

Tags: wordpress, popup, modal-dialog, contact-form-7

I have been attempting to create a modal contact form using the two plugins: Contact Form 7 and Easy Fancy Box.

I am also using visual composer in order to build my site..

I have therefore created a 'Raw Html' element, and in the element I have the following code:

```
<a href="#contact_form_pop" class="fancybox">Contact Us</a>
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
 <div id="contact_form_pop">
   <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1"]'); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

This does not work and the browser seems to comment out the php code, I know that php is a server side language but I was simply following a tutorial I found. The result is this when the button is clicked:

[image]

I then tried the code without the php and wordpress' 'do_shortcode', as another tutorial instructed:

```
<a href="#contact_form_pop" class="fancybox">Contact Us</a>
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
 <div id="contact_form_pop">
   [contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1"]
 </div>
</div>
```

This also didn't work and resulted in:

[image]

If anyone could help me to circumnavigate these issues and create a modal/pop-up contact form whilst using visual composer (I ahve built most of my site using it) I would be extremely greatful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pasted exactly works, the problem is that the shortcode is not picked up by wordpress. Make sure you paste the code in a text block, and the mode of the text block is 'Text' not 'Visual'.

Just tested and it works fine.

Comment: Yea everything seems to work fine, but the shortcode is not executing, as you said. When you said it works fine, do you mean the contact form is popping up for you?? Still struggling to get this popup contact form working - you'd think many people had done this before..

Comment: The contact form is popping up, yust fine. Dit you add the code in the text block?

Comment: Okay I got it working,. I'm not sure why it wasn;t working yesterday/last time I was trying, I didn't change anything. Thanks for the responses :)

Comment: Okay, that are the nicest fixes (frustrating ) ;)

Answer (score 0):

instead of only typing the shortcode use the correct function:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1"]'); ?>
```

if you want to store the shortcode inside a php variable, you can use this:

```
$my_shortcode = '[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1"]';
echo do_shortcode( $my_shortcode );
```